# Python executable built for M1 Macs fails with "(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')"

Tags: python, x86, pyinstaller, importerror, apple-m1

I’m trying to build a single file executable that will run on an Arm Mac, when built from an Intel mac. I’m using `pyinstaller` from a poetry environment to do this with the appropriate `onefile` and `target-arch` flags:

```
poetry run pyinstaller --onefile --target-arch=arm64 --paths .venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages ./test_app/app.py
```

It bundles and executes on Arm Macs correctly when the contents of `[app.py](http://app.py)` is a simple print statement:

```
print("hello world")
```

It fails, however, when I do something slightly more complex with dependencies such as `nltk`:

```
import argparse
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

def analyze_sentiment(text):
    sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    sentiment_scores = sid.polarity_scores(text)
    compound_score = sentiment_scores['compound']

    if compound_score >= 0:
        return 'positive'
    else:
        return 'negative'

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple Sentiment Analysis')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--text', type=str, required=True,
                        help='Input text for sentiment analysis')
    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
    args = parse_arguments()
    text = args.text
    result = analyze_sentiment(text)
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Specifically, I receive the following error when attempting to run this on M1 macs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_nltk.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "nltk/__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "nltk/text.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "nltk/tokenize/casual.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "regex/regex.py", line 421, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "regex/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/private/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/h1/9dzghzlx0xgcdw3j5yjk0hg00000gn/T/_MEIOOdlhi/regex/_regex.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
[86009] Failed to execute script 'pyi_rth_nltk' due to unhandled exception!
```

It appears that, though `pyinstaller` is successfully bundling for `arm64`, I’m getting an incompatible architecture problem from one the sub-dependencies when I execute it on an M1 mac: `(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')`. This is causing the overall executable to fail with `[86009] Failed to execute script 'pyi_rth_nltk' due to unhandled exception!`

What do I need to do to get Python executables built from an Intel mac to work on M1 macs?